# Linking json objects on generated GUID values

Tags: javascript, python, json, npm, awk

I am looking for a way to automate a tedious human-defying work of linking multiple JSON objects on random GUIDs.

There are several interlinked JSON-formatted files:

```
{
    "name": "some.interesting.name",
    "description": "helpful description",
    "instanceId": "random-GUID.for.some.interesting.name",
    "policies": [
        {
        "name": "some.interesting.name-policy",
        "instanceId": "random-GUID.for.some.interesting.name-policy"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
       "one": {
         "ref": "!some.interesting.name-2#random-GUID.for.some.interesting.name-2"
       }
    ]
}
```

The names are static and readable.
The files location is static and follows the name structure.

The InstanceId need to change every time a developer makes the tiniest change in any of the files.
Looking for a tool, or perhaps ideas on how to write one, to randomly generate and insert GUIDs in correct places in every file in the set.

Note: we are successfully using [npm nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) for GUID generation, so coming up with random values is solved.

Providing a minimal testable example.
The input would be configuration directory and all files under it.

Policy file:
configuration/policy/my_policy.js

```
{
   "name" : "policy.my_policy"
   "instanceId": "{$policy.my_policy}"
 
   "assets": [
       {  
         "user-info": "!assets.current_user_info#{$assets.current_user_info}"
       },
   ]

   "commands": [
      {
         "update-user": "!commands.update_admin_user#{$commands.update_admin_user}"
       }
   ]
}
```

configuration/assets/current_user_info.js

```
{
   "name" : "assets.current_user_info"
   "instanceId": "{$assets.current_user_info}"
   "attribute": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "admin"
   }
}
```

configuration/commands/update_admin_user.js

```
{
   "name" : "commands.update_admin_user"
   "instanceId": "{$commands.update_admin_user}"
   
   "inputType": {
      "name": "assets.current_user_info"
      "instanceId": "{$assets.current_user_info}"
   }
 }
```

The output would be the same files, probably copied to an output directory, in the same folder structure,
where variables

```
$assets.current_user_info
$commands.update_admin_user
$policy.my_policy
```

are substituted with GUID values in all files, generated using npm nanoid or a similar library.

Policy file:
configuration/policy/my_policy.js

```
{
   "name" : "policy.my_policy"
   "instanceId": "b35970fe-96dd-481d-a244-8880cc0cb818"
 
   "assets": [
       {  
         "user-info": "!assets.current_user_info#c3a17d65-921d-4cc4-9e23-5d40bd519289}"
       },
   ]

   "commands": [
      {
         "update-user": "!commands.update_admin_user#52a9a82e-a4e4-42f1-8376-a4e5ac06c9bd"
       }
   ]
}
```

configuration/assets/current_user_info.js

```
{
   "name" : "assets.current_user_info"
   "instanceId": "c3a17d65-921d-4cc4-9e23-5d40bd519289"
   "attribute": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "admin"
   }
}
```

configuration/commands/update_admin_user.js

```
{
   "name" : "commands.update_admin_user"
   "instanceId": "52a9a82e-a4e4-42f1-8376-a4e5ac06c9bd"
   
   "inputType": {
      "name": "assets.current_user_info"
      "instanceId": "c3a17d65-921d-4cc4-9e23-5d40bd519289"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Python script that uses uuid.uuid4() to generate the GUIDs for instanceIds and fills the values in all files.  Files are copied from src/ to output/, with the same directory structure.
Using python3.

```
# Import the os module, for the os.walk function
import os
import re
import uuid

# Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = 'src'
outputDir = 'output'

pattern = re.compile("{\$((\w*\.)*(\w)*)}")
instanceId = set([])

def findInstanceIdName(fileName):
    # print("Looking for instanceIds in " + fileName);
    found = [];
    for i, line in enumerate(open(fileName)):
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
            found_match = match.group();
            found.append(found_match);
    return found;

def generateInstanceIdValue(nameList):
    values = {}
    for instanceName in nameList:
        values[instanceName] = str(uuid.uuid4());
    return values;

def processFile(inputFileName, outputFileName, instanceIdValues):
    with open(inputFileName, "r") as inputFile, open(outputFileName, "w") as outputFile:
        line = inputFile.read();
        # print("Found line: <" + line + ">");
        for key in instanceIdValues.keys():
            line = line.replace(key, instanceIdValues[key]);
        outputFile.write(line);


for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    # print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        fullFileName = dirName + "/" + fname;
        instanceId.update(findInstanceIdName(fullFileName));

instanceIdValues = generateInstanceIdValue(instanceId);
#print(instanceIdValues);

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for fname in fileList:
        outputDirName = outputDir + dirName[len(rootDir):];
        os.makedirs(outputDirName, exist_ok=True);
        fullFileName = dirName + "/" + fname;
        outputFileName = outputDir + fullFileName[len(rootDir):];
        processFile(fullFileName, outputFileName, instanceIdValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

The input:

```
$ cat vars2guids
$assets.current_user_info       c3a17d65-921d-4cc4-9e23-5d40bd519289
$commands.update_admin_user     52a9a82e-a4e4-42f1-8376-a4e5ac06c9bd
$policy.my_policy               b35970fe-96dd-481d-a244-8880cc0cb818

$ find configuration -type f -name '*.js'
configuration/assets/current_user_info.js
configuration/commands/update_admin_user.js
configuration/policy/my_policy.js

$ head -n 50 $(find configuration -type f -name '*.js')
==> configuration/assets/current_user_info.js <==
{
   "name" : "assets.current_user_info"
   "instanceId": "{$assets.current_user_info}"
   "attribute": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "admin"
   }
}

==> configuration/commands/update_admin_user.js <==
{
   "name" : "commands.update_admin_user"
   "instanceId": "{$commands.update_admin_user}"

   "inputType": {
      "name": "assets.current_user_info"
      "instanceId": "{$assets.current_user_info}"
   }
}

==> configuration/policy/my_policy.js <==
{
   "name" : "policy.my_policy"
   "instanceId": "{$policy.my_policy}"

   "assets": [
       {
         "user-info": "!assets.current_user_info#{$assets.current_user_info}"
       },
   ]

   "commands": [
      {
         "update-user": "!commands.update_admin_user#{$commands.update_admin_user}"
       }
   ]
}
```

The tool:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
while IFS= read -r file; do

    printf '\n###########\nUpdating %s\n' "$file" >&2

    awk '
        NR==FNR { v2g[$1]=$2; next }
        {
            for (var in v2g) {
                if ( s=index($0,var) ) {
                    guid = v2g[var]
                    $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) guid substr($0,s+length(var))
                }
            }
            print
        }
    ' vars2guids "$file" # > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" "$file"

done < <(find configuration -type f -name '*.js')
```

The output:

```
$ ./tst.sh

###########
Updating configuration/assets/current_user_info.js
{
   "name" : "assets.current_user_info"
   "instanceId": "{c3a17d65-921d-4cc4-9e23-5d40bd519289}"
   "attribute": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "admin"
   }
}

###########
Updating configuration/commands/update_admin_user.js
{
   "name" : "commands.update_admin_user"
   "instanceId": "{52a9a82e-a4e4-42f1-8376-a4e5ac06c9bd}"

   "inputType": {
      "name": "assets.current_user_info"
      "instanceId": "{c3a17d65-921d-4cc4-9e23-5d40bd519289}"
   }
}

###########
Updating configuration/policy/my_policy.js
{
   "name" : "policy.my_policy"
   "instanceId": "{b35970fe-96dd-481d-a244-8880cc0cb818}"

   "assets": [
       {
         "user-info": "!assets.current_user_info#{c3a17d65-921d-4cc4-9e23-5d40bd519289}"
       },
   ]

   "commands": [
      {
         "update-user": "!commands.update_admin_user#{52a9a82e-a4e4-42f1-8376-a4e5ac06c9bd}"
       }
   ]
}
```

When done with initial testing remove the `#` from `# > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" "$file"` to have the original files updated by the tool instead of it just printing to stdout.

To create the `vars2guids` file by generating a guid per variable found in the .js files and assuming variables always look like `$word-chars.word-chars` inside `{...}` and nothing else looks like that:

```
vars=( $(find configuration -type f -name '*.js' -exec awk '
    {
        while ( match($0,/\{\$[[:alnum:]_]+\.[[:alnum:]_]+}/) ) {
            print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
            $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
    }
' {} + | sort -u) )

for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
    guid=$(echo "$RANDOM")
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$var" "$guid"
done # > vars2guids
```

The above will output:

```
$assets.current_user_info       29283
$commands.update_admin_user     28057
$policy.my_policy       1187
```

Change `echo "$RANDOM"` to whatever command you run to generate a GUID. Uncomment the `# > vars2guids` to have it write the output to `vars2guids` instead of stdout.

So after all testing your script could look like this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1

vars=( $(find configuration -type f -name '*.js' -exec awk '
    {
        while ( match($0,/\{\$[[:alnum:]_]+\.[[:alnum:]_]+}/) ) {
            print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
            $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
    }
' {} + | sort -u) )

for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
    guid=$(echo "$RANDOM")
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$var" "$guid"
done > vars2guids

while IFS= read -r file; do

    printf '\n###########\nUpdating %s\n' "$file" >&2

    awk '
        NR==FNR { v2g[$1]=$2; next }
        {
            for (var in v2g) {
                if ( s=index($0,var) ) {
                    guid = v2g[var]
                    $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) guid substr($0,s+length(var))
                }
            }
            print
        }
    ' vars2guids "$file" > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" "$file"

done < <(find configuration -type f -name '*.js')
```

Comment: spent some time figuring out how to read find output in that piece... 
Built a python script to do this, seems simpler.

Thank you for your help! Your scripts were instrumental.